# How to define permissions needed to execute a stored procedure with chained permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know how to give execute permission to a user for a stored procedure. The challenge is to define all other objects that the user needs permission on because of the queries inside the stored procedure.

Is there any simpler method to identify the chained permissions required on top of the basic execute permission on the SP. May be a complex sql query or a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `sp_depends 'Your_Procedure_name'` to determine all the dependant objects and then check the permissions accordingly.

Comment: That's a good start. Anything you know that gets me the actual queries for permission along with it?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114994/script-to-show-all-the-permissions-for-a-table check this out